# Regex not matching all the paranthesis substrings

Tags: python, regex, string, match, findall

'''txt = "But in any event, (not all) Christians believe
in the same theology, such as the one Latter-day Saints believe in.  (They
will cry "heresy" and other accusations of "perverting" the doctrines of
the Bible, while they themselves believe in a myriad of interpretations, as
found in their catechisms and various do-it-yourself Bible-study manuals)

As for me, I have a personal conviction that the pre-existance scenario as
explained above, is most in harmony with Biblical doctrine, some Dead Sea
Scroll books, the pseudographion, other  sources, and last but not
least, modern-day revelation on the subject." '''

I want to match (not all) and (They ...manuals). But whatever i try i am fetching either the second substring or the first.
I want to fetch both the substrings. i.e. all the substrings within paranthesis
Can someone help me out on this.??

Comment: Please post your code and expected output so we can help you further with that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parenthesis in regular expressions are used to indicate groups. If you want to match them literally, you must 'escape' them:

```
import re
found = re.findall(r'\(.*?\)', text)
print(found)
```

Outputs:

```
['(not all)', '(They will cry "heresy" and other accusations of "perverting" the doctrines of the Bible, while they themselves believe in a myriad of interpretations, as found in their catechisms and various do-it-yourself Bible-study manuals)']
```